# What is System.Web.dll work?

Tags: c#, dll, web

I'm going on the process about network.

here is the phrase that occur frequently "System.Web.dll",

we all know the file "System.Web.dll" is very important to website,

but how does it exactly effect on the website,

can I continue to browser my web after I delete the file ?

what does it effect to my website ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Web.Dll is old library responsible for whole http-protocol working. requests sending and creation.

You can not live without in either ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web forms because it contains HttpContext - class which is responsible for client-server communications.

If you need to use not web, but networks like LAN you probably need System.Net.dll

Comment: please ask questions in a precise and clear way, also try to use correct spellings so it can help other users as well